# SSAS TOM Net connect to Tabular from a different machine using a particular user

Tags: ssas, connection-string, analysisservices, tom

I'm trying to connect my Net Core API to the SQL Server Analysis Services server using the library TOM. The connection string is:

```
string ConnectionStringSSAS = "Provider=MSOLAP; Data Source=xxIpServerxx;User ID=xxuserxx;Password=xxpswsxx;Persist Security Info=True; Impersonation Level=Impersonate";
```

When I try to connect to server appear my problem

```
server.Connect(ConnectionStringSSAS);
```

Notes:

- The Analysis Services server is in a remote machine
- The Analysis Services server is using a different domain that my local machine. For example, my user is enterprise/myUser but in the server is localDomain/OtherUser

How could connect to the server using a particular user?

If I open Visual Studio using "run as" script with the server's user then I can connect and all is working fine.
But if I open normally I can't do it. I think that in that moment is using my local user.

If I put this in production, I couldn't do that "run as"